# Is there a way to find out which wonders have already been built in Civilization 6?

Tags: civilization-6

I'm playing Civilization 6 and I would like to see a list of completed world wonders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Antarctic Late Summer Patch, March 2019, Firaxis added a Search functionality into the game. In the development videos it was stated that this functionality was being included within the base game as well, so purchasing Gathering Storm should not be required. Using this feature you should be able to search for a term like "Wonder" and in theory it will allow you to cycle through the ones that have been created. Worst case you could search for them by name.

This strategy was mentioned by Carl during the video as a practice that you could do prior to committing hammers to producing a wonder, you could check to see if someone else had already started it.

Also I think this might only apply to tiles that you have had previous visibility to, but I would have to double check that mechanic to be certain.

Comment: A bit dated, but this indeed works for completed and under construction wonders. Ctl-F-> Wonders (or the name of the wonder). I was able to see wonders built on tiles I had discovered but didn't have visibility to; I was unable to see wonders on areas of the map not yet explored.

Comment: Can we have a picture of this search feature in action? I can't find it

Comment: I actually don't have the game installed at the moment, so here is a link to the video I referenced above: https://youtu.be/d-3iy78udTQ. I skipped through the video to find him using search and found an instance around 48:20. But they talk about how to use it super early.

Comment: It does work, but indeed only for wonders that are visible on the map.